# How to prepare an initial state for variational quantum algorithms?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-state

I would like to prepare an initial state for variational quantum algorithms.

The initial state should include the following states: $|000\rangle, |010\rangle, |100\rangle$, and $|001\rangle$.

How can I prepare this initial state?

FYI, I referred to [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.120.210501).
In this paper, the circuit creates $|100\rangle$, $|101\rangle$, and $|001\rangle$.

In addition, the Hamiltonian I want to solve is 
$$
H = - \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon \sum_{i=1}^{N} Z_i + \frac{1}{4} V \sum_{i,j=1}^N(X_iXj - Y_iY_j) \;,$$
where $\varepsilon$ and $V$ is the coefficients and $N$ is the number of quits.

Answer (score 3):

To prepare this state specifically, start with $|000\rangle$ and apply H to the 0th and 1st qubits, yielding

$$ \frac{1}{4} (|000\rangle + |010\rangle + |100\rangle + |110\rangle) $$

Then, we can apply the Toffoli gate to the 0th and 1st qubit with the 2nd qubit as the target, yielding:

$$ \frac{1}{4} (|000\rangle + |010\rangle + |100\rangle + |111\rangle) $$

Now, apply a CNOT with 2nd qubit as control and 0th and 1st qubits as targets, yielding:

$$ \frac{1}{4} (|000\rangle + |010\rangle + |100\rangle + |001\rangle) $$

As desired.

---

*More talk on state prep*

Because your Hamiltonian is relatively simple, both Trotterization and Variational Quantum Eigensolvers (VQEs) could work. I'll refer to the [VQE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.3061.pdf), because it talks more about quantum state prep, specifically:

> If a quantum state is characterized by an exponentially
>   large number of parameters, it cannot be prepared with
>   a polynomial number of operations. The set of efficiently
>   preparable states are therefore characterized by polynomially many parameters, and we choose a particular set
>   of ansatz states of this type.

Basically, especially for quantum chem algorithms with complex ansatzes, we need efficient state preparation algorithms that are parametrized with a polynomial number of parameters. This is still an active area of research and especially important for Trotterization/VQEs/Qubitization, etc.

Comment: To calculate with VQE, we have to prepare the initial state as the following style: $$a|000> + b|010> + c|100> + d|100>$$ with $$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 1$$. Am I right ?

Comment: @Ashy all quantum states need to be in the form $\sum_{i} a_i |i \rangle $ where $ \sum_{i} |a_i|^2 = 1$ and $a_i \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: To calculate the minimum value with VQE, I think we should prepare the initial state with some parameters.

Comment: @Ashy, do you have a specific question? If so, I'd recommend creating a new question

Comment: you have to change the initial state |x(theta)> with respect to theta to find the minimu value of <x(theta) | H | x(theta) > for variational calculations. However, the state you mentioned is not changeable. Anyway, I make a new question. Thank you very much.